# mysql-how to select id with loops

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to select id with loops:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$str= '8,2,3,4,5,6,7';
$strr=explode(',' , $str);
$i=0;
while($i<count($strr)){
    $sql = "select id,name from `live_table` where `id`='$strr[$i]' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $i++;

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $result_array[] = $row;
        }
        foreach ($result_array as $rows) {
            // The output
         echo '<tr>';           
         echo '<td class="small">'.$rows['id'].'</td>';
         echo '<td class="small">'.$rows['name'].'</td>';
         echo '</tr>';
     }
 }
 }
 ?>
```

output:

> 8,Bell,8,Bell,2,Sydney,8,Bell,2,Sydney,3,Chelsea,8,Bell,2,Sydney,3,Chelsea,4,Alec,8,Bell,2,Sydney,3,Chelsea,4,Alec,5,Brenden,8,Bell,2,Sydney,3,Chelsea,4,Alec,5,Brenden,6,Nadine,8,Bell,2,Sydney,3,Chelsea,4,Alec,5,Brenden,6,Nadine,7,Prescott,

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: you have a backtick at }`<br> typo or is this in your code?

Comment: I want out put:<br>
'id:8,2,3,4,5,6,7'<br>don't repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `$result_array` before executing the while loop for every iteration.

**Modified Code Block:**

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $result_array = array(); // ADD THIS LINE

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $result_array[] = $row;
    }
    foreach ($result_array as $rows) {
        // The output
        echo '<tr>';           
        echo '<td class="small">'.$rows['id'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="small">'.$rows['name'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

**You can also optimize this code by using HTML block inside the while loop:**

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<tr>';           
            echo '<td class="small">'.$row['id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="small">'.$row['name'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }        
}
```